# How to deserialize an xml and pass it through wcf service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, wcf

I have an `xml` as shown below and want to pass it as a response from `wcf` service.What i did is, i used Visual studio to generate c# classes from `xml` and then deserilize the xml with the classes generated from VS.Data is coming in Soap UI from WCF service but when i click validate in soap ui, it is throwing error

**EDIT on 250320**

Finally i reached to single error like
line 17: Invalid xsi:type qname: 'c:string' in element SITE_NAME@http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ITSM_GIS_NRMIntegration.BusinessObjects
c# code

```
namespace ITSM_GIS_NRMIntegration
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class GisItsmService : IGisItsmService
    {
      Datatable   dtcustomerSiteDtls = dtcustomerSiteDtls.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("CBCM_PARTY_ID"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("CBCM_PARTY_NAME"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("SERVICE"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("SITENAME"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("NODENAME"))
            .CopyToDataTable();
                XElement allSites = doc.Root;
    
                foreach (var idGroup in dtcustomerSiteDtls.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("CBCM_PARTY_ID")))
                {
                    XElement siteNode = new XElement("PARTY_SITE_NODES");
                    allSites.Add(siteNode);
    
    
                    siteNode.Add(new XElement("CBCM_PARTY_ID", idGroup.Key));
                    siteNode.Add(new XElement("CBCM_PARTY_NAME", idGroup.First().Field<string>("CBCM_PARTY_NAME")));
    
                    DataTable dtfilter = dtcustomerSiteDtls.Select("CBCM_PARTY_ID = '" + idGroup.Key.ToString() + "'").CopyToDataTable();
    
                    foreach (var service in dtfilter.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SERVICE")))
                    {
                        XElement partyServices = new XElement("PARTY_SERVICES");
                        siteNode.Add(partyServices);
                        partyServices.Add(new XElement("SERVICE_NAME", service.Key));
    
                        XElement serviceSites = new XElement("SERVICE_SITES");
                        partyServices.Add(serviceSites);
                        foreach (var serviceSite in service.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SITENAME")))
                        {
                            serviceSites.Add(new XElement("SITE_NAME", serviceSite.Key));
    
                            XElement siteNodes = new XElement("SITE_NODES");
                            serviceSites.Add(siteNodes);
    
                            string[] nodeNames = serviceSite.Select(x => x.Field<string>("NODENAME")).Distinct().ToArray();
                            foreach (string nodeName in nodeNames)
                            {
                                siteNodes.Add(new XElement("NODE_NAME", nodeName));
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
    
    
    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        XmlSerializer myItemSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(getCustomerSites));
        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            sitedetailsResObj = (getCustomerSites)myItemSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

**C# classes used to serialize**

```
namespace ITSM_GIS_NRMIntegration.BusinessObjects
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class getCustomerSites:ResponseBase
    {

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES[] pARTY_SITE_NODESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PARTY_SITE_NODES")]
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES[] PARTY_SITE_NODES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARTY_SITE_NODESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARTY_SITE_NODESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES
    {

        private uint cBCM_PARTY_IDField;

        private string cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField;

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES[] pARTY_SERVICESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public uint CBCM_PARTY_ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cBCM_PARTY_IDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cBCM_PARTY_IDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CBCM_PARTY_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PARTY_SERVICES")]
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES[] PARTY_SERVICES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARTY_SERVICESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARTY_SERVICESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES
    {

        private string sERVICE_NAMEField;

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES sERVICE_SITESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string SERVICE_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sERVICE_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sERVICE_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES SERVICE_SITES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sERVICE_SITESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sERVICE_SITESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [KnownType(typeof(getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES))]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES
    {

        private object[] sITE_NAMEField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NAME", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NODES", typeof(getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES))]
        public object[] SITE_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sITE_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sITE_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES
    {

        private string[] nODE_NAMEField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NODE_NAME")]
        public string[] NODE_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nODE_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nODE_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Error in SOAP UI is as shown below

An[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210295/discussion-on-question-by-peter-how-to-desalinize-an-xml-and-pass-it-through-wcf).

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to deserialize the xml.  Linq is much faster to deserialize than the code below.  So you have to decide if it is better to use your code or the code below.  Usually I recommend if you have a schema (and the classes) and trying to get all the data it is better to use serialization.  You are putting results into a datatable which I then recommend xml linq.  I just want to so why I suggested to remove the base class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(getCustomerSites));
            getCustomerSites sites = (getCustomerSites)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class getCustomerSites //: ResponseBase
    {

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES[] pARTY_SITE_NODESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PARTY_SITE_NODES")]
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES[] PARTY_SITE_NODES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARTY_SITE_NODESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARTY_SITE_NODESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODES
    {

        private uint cBCM_PARTY_IDField;

        private string cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField;

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES[] pARTY_SERVICESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public uint CBCM_PARTY_ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cBCM_PARTY_IDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cBCM_PARTY_IDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CBCM_PARTY_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cBCM_PARTY_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PARTY_SERVICES")]
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES[] PARTY_SERVICES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARTY_SERVICESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARTY_SERVICESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICES
    {

        private string sERVICE_NAMEField;

        private getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES sERVICE_SITESField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string SERVICE_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sERVICE_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sERVICE_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES SERVICE_SITES
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sERVICE_SITESField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.sERVICE_SITESField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    //[KnownType(typeof(getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES))]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES
    {

        private object[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NAME", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NODES", typeof(getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES))]
        public object[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES
    {

        private string[] nODE_NAMEField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NODE_NAME")]
        public string[] NODE_NAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nODE_NAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nODE_NAMEField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The moderator locked the main question.  I saw your changes from 2 hours ago.  Looks like you found the schema and where the error is in the schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.What ever i did previously was correct, those in SOAP UI where not errors only validation .The real issue was with client Team i mean Java team, the way they were consuming :) Not from my side.I will delete this question soon.Thanks a lot for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using two properties instead of one?

```
   public partial class getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITES
    {

        private object[] itemNamesField;
        private object[] itemNodessField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NAME", typeof(string))]
        public object[] ItemNames
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemNamesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemNamesField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SITE_NODES", typeof(getCustomerSitesPARTY_SITE_NODESPARTY_SERVICESSERVICE_SITESSITE_NODES))]
        public object[] ItemNodes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemNodesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemNodesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.What ever i did previously was correct, those in SOAP UI where not errors only validation .The real issue was with client Team i mean Java team, the way they were consuming :) Not from my side.I will delete this question soon.Thanks a lot for your suggestion